# What is the quickest way of replacing 0 by 1 and vice-versa in a stream?

Tags: text-processing, sed, performance

Given a string composed of `0`s and `1`s, my goal is to replace 0 by 1 and vice-versa. Example:

Input

```
111111100000000000000
```

Intended output

```
000000011111111111111
```

I tried, unsuccessfully, the following `sed` command

```
echo '111111100000000000000' | sed -e 's/0/1/g ; s/1/0/g'
000000000000000000000
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use [`tr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) for this, its main purpose is character translation:

```
echo 111111100000000000000 | tr 01 10
```

Your `sed` command replaces all 0s with 1s, resulting in a string containing only 1s (the original 1s and all the replaced 0s), and then replaces all 1s with 0s, resulting in a string containing only 0s.

On long streams, `tr` is faster than `sed`; for a 100MiB file:

```
$ time tr 10 01 < bigfileof01s > /dev/null
tr 10 01 < bigfileof01s > /dev/null  0.07s user 0.03s system 98% cpu 0.100 total

$ time sed y/10/01/ < bigfileof01s > /dev/null
sed y/10/01/ < bigfileof01s > /dev/null  3.91s user 0.11s system 99% cpu 4.036 total
```

Comment: Another argument for `tr` is it should work with any file/stream. Long stream of 0s and 1s is not a text file in formal terms of POSIX. The specification for `sed` says "the input files shall be text files", while for `tr` it's "any type of file". I believe GNU `sed` has an unlimited input buffer (certainly not limited to `{LINE_MAX}` bytes) and therefore it works with `bigfileof01s`. Other implementations may not.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The question explicitly mentions "string".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Does "string" mean no line exceeds `{LINE_MAX}`?

Comment: @kamil perhaps. Why shouldn’t it?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Are you asking why "string" shouldn't mean? Or why some line shouldn't exceed? The [POSIX definition of the text file](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) states "no line exceeds `{LINE_MAX}` bytes in length". `sed` may or may not accept a file that doesn't comply. `tr` must accept any file. This is my point. My first comment might be misleading for users not familiar with "formal terms of POSIX", now it should be clear. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) [POSIX definition of "string"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_375) requires a null byte. I interpret this regarding the representation in memory, not in files (e.g. text files cannot contain null bytes at all). Anyway, it says nothing about length; plus `sed` is obliged to work with input in form of "text files", not "strings". What definition of "string" are you using? and why should it matter to the `{LINE_MAX}` issue?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Posix requires that sed should accept "text files". Text files should not exceed {LINE_MAX} on any line nor contain any NUL character. So, is reasonable to understand that the OP is meaning: "one line of text followed by a newline character" from his example of input. If that is the case, then sed should process that input if limited to {LINE_MAX} per line.

Comment: Gee: 3.91 / 0.007 means a factor of 55.85 times, is that much difference correct? I get a quite lower factor, around 9 times.

Comment: @Isaac it’s consistent on the system I used to run the test. I just ran the test on another system, where I get times around 3s for `sed` and 0.05s for `tr`, a factor of 60.

Comment: As always, with these kinds of measurements, it’s hard to compare because we don’t know exactly what’s going on @Isaac. One could be doing better in the cache or with fs interactions. We don’t know from just the timings

Answer (score 40):

Although [`tr` is the right tool for this job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562467/65304) you can do it in `sed` using the `y` (transliteration) command rather than the `s` (substitution) command:

```
$ echo '111111100000000000000' | sed 'y/01/10/'
000000011111111111111
```

`y` is basically `sed`'s internal implementation of `tr` - with all the overhead that implies.

Answer (score 14):

A way is `echo "111111100000000000000" | sed 's/1/2/g;s/0/1/g;s/2/0/g'`

Comment: This approach does work, but it has two disadvantages: it’s not generalisable (the temporary replacement character must not be present in the input, which of course is the case here), and it’s much slower than `sed`’s `y` command, let alone `tr`.

Comment: thank you @StephenKitt . I have written a solution especially to show the error of the input question: in it the command overwrites itself. My example is not good, but it might be a little "educational"

Comment: Yes, I agree it’s useful and educational!

Answer (score 1):

Probably a slow method, but it does it the binary way, using shell built-in arithmetic:

```
echo '111111100000000000000' |
  while read -rn1 b; do
    printf '%1d' $((b^1))
  done
```

Or to handle the binary stream by byte chunks:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Populate a byte to inverted binary string array
declare -a byte_binstring=()
for ((byte=0; byte<=255; byte++)); do
  for ((bit=0; bit<=7; bit++)); do
    printf -v byte_binstring[byte] '%1s' "$((!(byte>>bit&1)))${byte_binstring[byte]}"
  done
done

# Read input stream by chunks of 8 bits max
while read -rn8 bin_str; do
  # $((2#$bin_str)) converts the bit string into a byte value
  # using shell built-in base-2 arithmetic conversion
  # byte_binstring[$((2#$bin_str))] gets the string matching this byte value
  # ${#bin_str}} gives the number of bits read (string length)
  # extract the last n characters from string matching
  # number of byte read
  # ${byte_binstring[$((2#$bin_str))]: -${#bin_str}}
  # This prints the inverted binary representation from the read bits stream
  printf '%s' "${byte_binstring[$((2#$bin_str))]: -${#bin_str}}"
done
```

Comment: Going by its progress so far, the first method would take over a week to work its way through 100 MiB on my system, *i.e.* somewhere over 7 million times slower than `tr` ;-).

Comment: In the end, this took 8679m9.819s (8129m9.669s user and 2694m2.270s system), just over six days.

Answer (score 1):

If your string contains only a single line and is composed of only 0s and 1s then you can use this

```perl
echo "111111100000000000000" |
    perl -e 'while (read(STDIN, $b, 1)) { print chr(ord($b) ^ 1); } print "\n";'
```

If the string can contain multiple lines then just change `perl -e` to `perl -ne` and change the way to read the bytes (since `read` needs a file handle)

```perl
echo -e "111111100000000000000\n0001111010101" |
    perl -ne 'while (/(.)/g) { print chr(ord($1)^1) } print "\n"'
```

However that way each line is broken into a string, so it may not be very efficient for big files. In that case a little check is necessary

```perl
echo "122111111034000000000abc0000" | perl -e 'while (read(STDIN, $b, 1)) {
    print ($b eq '0' or $b eq '1' ? chr(ord($b) ^ 1) : $b) } print "\n";'
```

As you can see, this way it also works for strings that contain characters other than `'0'` and `'1'`